# Are there only 2 possible orientations of ordered bases in $n$-dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a linear transformation $T$ on a $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, the determinant of $T$ can either be positive or negative.

For $n=2$, this corresponds to the fact that there are 2 possible orientations of the ordered bases $b_1$ and $b_2$ in 2-dimensional space (clockwise and anti-clockwise). Similarly for $n=3$, there are 2 possible orientations of the ordered bases $b_1$, $b_2$ and $b_3$ in 3-dimensional space (left-handed and right-handed).

The ordered bases may be chosen as positively or negatively oriented in $2^n$ ways, but for $n=2$ and $3$, there are only 2 such combinations if we exclude those that are superimposable to each other.

Since the determinant of $T$ only takes a positive or negative value for $n>3$ too, does this imply that there are only 2 possible orientations of all the ordered bases in a $n$-dimensional vector space? If so, why?

Comment: In a four dimensional space you can choose two subspaces that are two dimensional and only have the zero vector in common. Each will have two possible orientations giving the entire space four.

Answer (score 1):

"Yes, for the reason you give": If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are ordered bases, there is a *unique* linear $T$ carrying one to the other (as ordered bases). By definition, the bases have *the same orientation* if $\det T > 0$ and have *opposite orientation* if $\det T < 0$.